# How i can insert video on my webpage

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to play my video on my web page, video is about two houre longe. the video is stored on the same server where i host the website. please provide me code so that i complete task. also suggest me best alternative to complete the same task.

I am using vb.net as language in asp.net and .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: I suggest uploading your video on another server, maybe use blip.tv or Vimeo for instance to host it. They'll give you some code to simply paste into your file and they'll take care of the rest in order to display the video on your site. A 2hr long video is going to get your hosting account out of allocated monthly traffic fast, presuming you don't have some sort of special arrangement allowing you unlimited traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the video must be in your server then use any web players like JW Player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

To embed JW Player:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="480" height="270" id="player1" name="<param name="movie" value="/jwplayer/player.swf">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=/data/bbb.mp4&autostart=true">
        <embed id="player1" name="player1" src="jwplayer/player.swf" width="480" height="270" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="file=http://localhost/upload/upload-play/videos/video(25).mp4&autostart=true"/> </object>
```

Download jwplayer and change the file path and player.swf path as you need...